# Detectar colisão de um retângulo rotacionado?

Tags: c#, geometria, xna

Estou usando o seguinte código para saber se um ponto está dentro de um retângulo:

```
public bool Intersect(ÍcaroDantasCollisions.Rectangle rectangle)
{
    if(x >= rectangle.x && x <= rectangle.x + rectangle.width)
    {
        if(y >= rectangle.y && y <= rectangle.y + rectangle.height)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Obs¹: O 'x' e 'y' soltos no código se referem às coordenadas do 'ponto'.

Obs²: Na classe retângulo estão presentes apenas a declaração das variáveis x, y, width e height.

Agora a pergunta, digamos que esse retângulo esteja rotacionado em 45º, como saber se o ponto se encontra colidindo com ele? Eu deveria obrigatoriamente usar polígonos?

Answer (score -1):

Achei a solução:

Primeiro você mede o ângulo de rotação do retângulo a partir da parte superior esquerda, depois é só girar o ponto numa direção contrária à direção do retângulo também a partir de sua origem, depois é só fazer a verificação como se o retângulo não estivesse rotacionado :D

Comment: Seria importante por uma solução real aqui. Se for apenas para apontar um link externo, melhor postar como comentário. Outra coisa, a "rotação" do ponto tem que ser em sentido contrário da do retângulo. Fora isso, sua pergunta não menciona qual é a origem da rotação, seria bom acrescentar lá este detalhe (e aproveitar para remover os ifs desnecessários, já que o retorno é bool). E mais uma coisa: a postagem indicada é muito ruim como solução. Fica a sugestão de postar um código real na resposta, para uma melhor avaliação, e para ajudar outros membros da comunidade com dúvida similar.

Comment: Eita! Realmente :O! A rotação tem que ser realmente em sentido contrário, desculpa ae!

Comment: Não precisa pedir desculpas, só avisei para te alertar do problema. Quanto ao resto, é só sugestão de melhoria para valorizar a resposta (e a pergunta também).

Comment: Dei uma melhorada.